# Is it possible to derive the correct QED Lagrangian without demanding local gauge invariance?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Usually, the correct interaction term $A_\mu \bar{\Psi} \gamma_\mu \Psi$ in the Lagrangian is derived by demanding local gauge invariance.

Is there any other argument that fixes the form of the interaction term like, e.g., conservation of electric charge?

Comment: Just pointing out that conservation of electric charge arises from global gauge invariance (or a global phase change), which is included by the local one. So conservation of charge would not be really a different argument.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could actually think if this interaction term being motivated precisely by demanding that conservation of charge be local, and not just global. If that's what you meant in the question, then the answer is yes. But I don't really see that as a different argument from the local gauge invariance one; maybe it's just a more physically appealing one.

Comment: @BrunoDeSouzaLeão thanks! I think this really depends on how you define the notions local and global. One possibility is that "local" means generated by functions with compact support. Then global transformations are not part of the local ones and the arguments are separate. Do you have a reference where the interaction term is motivated by demanding local charge conservation?

Comment: I was thinking of "local" in the sense of "being defined point by point", in which case you could introduce a position-dependent generator, but I acknowledge that might have been ambiguous. From the top of my head I have some lecture notes from a course I took a while ago, but they are written in Portuguese; let me try to look for something else.